# Using Laravel, how to get an image from an s3 private bucket via controller action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

Using Laravel, I want a unified get url for all images.  The images are stored in a private s3 bucket.

My current controller action:

```
    public function getImage(Request $request) {
        $file =  Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($request->filename, now()->addMinutes(5));
        return response()->file($file);
    }
```

In my view I am referencing this like:

```
{{ route('image', ['filename' => $user->meta->profile_image_url]) }}
```

The error I am get is: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: ...

The problem is that if I just drop the url access directly into the view it works fine.  I have done things like:

```
{{ Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($filePathFromDB, now()->addMinutes(5)) }}
```

Again, trying to unify my access to files.

--

I have worked on this some more and I have landed on an updated controller action:

```
    public function getImage(Request $request) {
      $adapter = Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getAdapter();       

      $command = $adapter->getClient()->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => $adapter->getBucket(),
        'Key'    => $adapter->getPathPrefix(). '' . $request->filename
      ]);

      $img = $adapter->getClient()->createPresignedRequest($command, '+20 minute');
      return response()->file($img->getUri());
}
```

the issue is that this returns an image url that has & and "

I have tried htmlspecialchars_decode

How do I get the url to respond clean?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily access the S3 private content from the controller. You can find the solution here:

[Access s3 bucket private content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61361351/5783617)

Answer (score -2):

In your view

```
{{ Html::image("$user->meta->profile_image_url", '', array('class' => 'img-responsive')) }}
```

in your user model

```
public function getProfileImageUrlAttribue {
    if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists($this->meta->profile_image_url)) {
        return $this->meta->profile_image_url;
    }else {
          //....
    }
}
```

I know you want to do it in the controller, but still the same logic use `Storage::disk('s3')->exists->`

[Laravel filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#retrieving-files)

Comment: I am not storing the whole url in the db.  Just the relevant part /img/filename.jpg.  Plus this is a S3 private bucket. That is why I am getting a temp url.  Additionally there are a ton of images across the system that I want to use the url for.

Comment: Then, you can use `Storage::url('file.jpg');`. Just an exmaple for file.jpg.

Comment: Thanks @julian-mendez, but `Storage::url('file.jpg');` returns 403.  I assume this is because of the private bucket

Comment: After re-reading this, it requires the laravelcollective package which I am not using.  Additionally it didn't answer the question for a private bucket.